# The solution of the parametric inequality $\frac{x-1}{3}-\frac{x+1}{a+3}>\frac{1}{5(a+3)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Proof:
The inequality after calculations becomes:

$$\frac{5(a+6)x-(5a+3)}{a+3}>0 \tag1$$

Since $\neg(a=3)$ we have by using trichotumy :

$$a+3>0\vee a+3<0\tag2$$

For $a+3>0$, $(1)$ becomes:

$$5(a+6)x>5a+3\tag3$$

But $a+3>0\Longrightarrow a+6>0$, hence $(3)$ becomes:

$$x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\tag4$$

For $a+3<0$, $(1)$ becomes :

$$5(a+6)x<5a+3\tag5$$

Thus by using $(2)$, $(4)$, $(5)$ AND the law of Constractive Dilεmma (From wwfs of the forms $R\vee Q,P\Longrightarrow S.Q\Longrightarrow R$ we infer $S\vee R$) we can conclude:

$$x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\vee 5(a+6)x<5a+3\tag6$$

But $$x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\Longrightarrow x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\tag7$$

Now let $$5(a+6)x<5a+3\tag8$$

Since for $a=-6$, $(8)$ becomes $0>-27$,which is impossible and by using the trichotomy law again we have:

$$a+6>0\vee a+6<0\tag9$$

For $a+6>0$, $(8)$ becomes:

$$x<\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\tag10$$

For $a+6<0$, $(8)$ becomes:

$$x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\tag11$$

Again from $(9)$, $(10)$, $(11)$ and using Constractive Dilemma we can conclude:

$$x<\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\vee x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\tag12$$

Thus, $$5(a+6)x<5a+3\Longrightarrow x<\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\vee x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\tag13$$

And finally from $(6)$, $(7)$ and $(13)$ and using again Constractive Dilemma we infer that:

$$x<\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\vee x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}$$

So we can say that for all values of $a$ except the values of $-6$ and $-3$ the solutions to the above inequality are:

$$x<\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}\vee x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}$$

Comment: Just what is your question?

Comment: is my proof correct??

Comment: What is the "Constractive Dilemma"? I get no English hits in Google. And if you want others to check a proof of yours, use the "proof-verification" tag on the question. I have added it for this question.

Comment: for $a>-3 $ the values of x that satisfy the original equation are:$x>\frac{5a+3}{5(a+6)}$ .So to find a particular value for x give any value to a for e.g $a=-1$ and see what is the corresponding valur for $x$

Comment: I have mention the general form of Constractive Dilemma in my OP,but let me state it again.From the wffs $p\vee q$, $p\Longrightarrow s$, $q\Longrightarrow r$,we may infer $s\vee r$

Comment: Yes, I did miss your definition of the Constractive Dilemma in your OP: sorry. However, you misstated it there. You wrote "$R\lor Q$" there but "$p\lor q$" in your comment. You should correct it in your OP.